# ctest in cmake: How to test output by allowing lines in different orders?

Tags: cmake, ctest

Normally, in most cases, ctest allows us to test the output of a certain command

```
add_test(sometest somecommand)
set_tests_properties(sometest PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION some_regex)
```

What if I wanna test the output to contain some lines and ONLY those lines in ANY orders? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What minimum version of cmake?